# How to hide Selection in JList

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I create several JLists by using DefaultListmModel, so I can add, edit and delete items in those JLists.
How can I hide the selection the user made?
So like the user clicks in JList 1 to edit the value with index 2 by double clicking on the item. So now the item with index value 2 is selected in the UI and it's blue.
My Question is: How can I hide this, so after editing/adding items in the JList, what do I have to do that the item which was selected isn't blue, so that you can't see what you selected before.

clearSelection() isn't working.

My code is the following (I shortened the JOptionPane stuff and the if else part):

```
for (int i=0; i < StringArray.length; i++) {
        DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for (int j=0; j < StringArray[i].length; j++) {
            model.addElement(StringArray[i][j]);

            if((StringArray[i].length -1)== j) {
            listbox = new JList<String>(model);
            Panel.add(listbox);

            listbox.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                         if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                            int index = listbox.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());

                            Object[] options = {"Add", "Edit", "Delete"};
                            //.... JOptionPane
                            if (ADDING) {
                                String tmpAddValue = JOptionPane...
                                model.addElement(tmpAddValue);
                            }
                            else if (EDITING) {
                                String tmpValue = JOptionPane...
                                model.setElementAt(tmpValue, index);
                            }
                            else if (DELETING) {
                                model.removeElementAt(index);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("No Button pushed");
                            }
                            listbox.clearSelection();
                       }      

                  }
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to clear the selection ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#clearSelection()  or just change the colors ? See handling colors example here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Comment: I want to clear the Selection and to change the color back to normal like the item wasn't selected

Comment: So use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#clearSelection()

Comment: I used the API doc but clearSelection() doesn't work =\